# Sufficient conditions to obtain a bound on a sum of matrix-weighted norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $\psi=(\psi_i)_{1 \leq i \leq m}$ and $\phi=(\phi_j)_{1 \leq j \leq n}$ be two collections of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d < \min(m,n)$, and let $w_{i,j}$ be some weights that sum to 1 ($\sum_{i,j} w_{i,j} =1$). Assume further that $\sum_{i} \psi_i \psi_i^T$ and $\sum_{j} \phi_j \phi_j^T$ are invertible.

I want to find sufficient conditions on $\phi$ and $\psi$ to have
$$\sum_{j} \left[\left(\sum_i w_{i,j}\psi_i\right)^T\left(\sum_{i} \psi_i \psi_i^T\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_i w_{i,j}\psi_i\right)\right] \leq \frac{1}{m}$$
and $$\sum_{i} \left[\left(\sum_j w_{i,j}\phi_j\right)^T\left(\sum_{j} \phi_j \phi_j^T\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_j w_{i,j}\phi_j\right)\right] \leq \frac{1}{n},$$ and I want this bound to be "sharp", in the sense that there exists $w$ as well as $\phi$ and $\psi$ following these conditions such that the inequality is an equality. It's fine if the inequalities/equalities are up to a constant that depends on $d$.

For example for $d=1$, my requirements become $$\sum_{j} \frac{(\sum_i w_{i,j}\psi_i)^2}{ \left\| \psi \right\|^2_2} \leq \frac{1}{m}$$
and $$\sum_{i} \frac{(\sum_j w_{i,j}\phi_j)^2}{\left\| \phi \right\|^2_2} \leq \frac{1}{n}.$$

And a sufficient condition is to have $\frac{\left\| \psi \right\|_{\infty}^2}{\left\| \psi \right\|^2_2} \leq \frac{1}{m}$ and $\frac{\left\| \phi \right\|^2_{\infty}}{\left\| \phi \right\|^2_2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Furthermore, if we choose every $\phi_i$ and $\psi_j$ to be 1, and $w_{1,1}=1$, we attain the bound.